Count groups of rows containing a single specific value into another column
Say we have a dataframe looking like this one below:
order_id product     seller
1        apple       a
1        grape       a
2        orange      a
2        strawberry  b
2        apple       b
3        apple       b
4        kiwi        a
4        orange      a
5        grape       c

My aim is to group them first by their order_id while just keeping all these orders whose products having been delivered by a unique seller. Hence, the output I desire to get would look as follows:
order_id product     seller
1        apple       a
1        grape       a
3        apple       b
4        kiwi        a
4        orange      a
5        grape       c

Is there a simple way to achieve it?

One method is using a CTE or subquery to qualify the order_id's.

Here's a method using a CTE to determine how many sellers are associated with each order, then you limit to orders with just one seller.
with seller_count as (
  select order_id, count(distinct seller) as sellers
  from orders
  group by order_id
  )
select o.*
from orders o
join seller_count sc
  on o.order_id = sc.order_id
where sc.sellers = 1

Here's a method that calls the table just once by using a couple dense_rank() functions (one sorting ASC and other DESC), then limit to where the rank is the same.
select 
 order_id, 
 product, 
 seller
from (
 select *, 
  dense_rank() over (partition by order_id order by seller) as dn1, 
  dense_rank() over (partition by order_id order by seller desc) as dn2
 from orders
)
where dn1 = dn2

See this fiddle.
